# Use pictures as links to different worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have pictures of several products. I have to link each picture with an Excel sheet in such a way that when I click on the picture, it will open the right Excel sheet. How can I do this?

yes these pictures are in my computer. these pictures are picture of the procducts and the person want to open the price bar of the products in the excel sheet when he click on the picture of the product. the excel sheet is complete. I have tried but could'nt find a solution. you some solution please. maybe have to upload them on a website first?

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done and what have you learned? Where are these pictures located, what sort of file/document/source? Right now your question lacks much of the information necessary to give you an answer. Use the EDIT button to add any and all necessary and relevant contextual information to the question itself.

Comment: And could you please[edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1406215/edit) to give us more info. We don't have access to your computer or your mind...

Comment: In the user scenario, are the clickable pictures in an Excel Workbook or is the user clicking on the picture's file icon located on the desktop (or some other folder)?

Answer (score 1):

First the set the Name of each picture to the Name of the desired destination sheet. *(so we have a Picture or Shape named "dog" and a worksheet also named "dog")*

Then assign this macro to all Pictures:

```
Sub ClickMe()
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name).Activate
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Macros are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the macro from the Excel window:

1. Click the associated Picture or Shape

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: went to the custimize ribbon and to macros how to assign this macro to all pictures?

Comment: Yes sir, thanks a lot. i have done it. complete all the steps but there is a problem. names C1.jpg is the picture name and when completing all these steps when click on the image C.jpg excel sheet dont opens ?????

Comment: @AdnanKhan  Rename the picture to match the worksheet name

Comment: hello sir when save amcro it gives me this message: "The following features cannot be saved in macro free books.   to save the file file in this way select no and then select the macro-enabled file type in the file type list"                                      what to do now???

Comment: @AdnanKhan  See my **EDIT#1** ...................especially the part about ***.XLSM***

Comment: yes sir, working on it. will let u know

Comment: Yes sir have done exactly like that done everything, also  macro is saved successfully with .xlsm but when click on the picture on desktop the excel sheet don't open. The name of the pic is Sheet1.jpg and the name of the sheet in excel is also sheet1.

Comment: i dont know what to do now ???

Comment: still its not working can some help ?????

Comment: @AdnanKhan  If the Name of the sheet is ***sheet1***, then the name of the picture must also be ***sheet1*** not ***Sheet1*** and not ***Sheet1.jpg***

Comment: have done it. when click on Sheet1 quickly opens "how do you want to open your file" and a list of programs opens. but dont open directly and when I select MS Excel from thge list of programs to open this pic pop up a message "This app cant run on your PC" whats to do now??????  plz reply as soon  as possible

Comment: hello sir plz reply soon i still cannot solve this pprobelm. i can even send u the screen shots if u want

Comment: @AdnanKhan  I cannot duplicate the error you are seeing.

Comment: sir when .jpg or .png is removed from a picture and its changed to only Sheet1 then the picture not opens at all but after following all the above mentioned steps when click on the picture with Sheet1.png or Sheet1.jgp pic opens but but the specific bar in the excel dont opens. how to do it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Insert Picture Into Cell:

1. Insert tab (on ribbon), Illustrations section, Pictures -> opens dialogue, Select image.
2. Size the image small enough and the cell large enough that the image fits within the cell.
3. Lock the image into the cell: Right click image, Size and Properties ... -> opens dialogue, Properties Section (expand if closed by clicking Properties), select Move and size with cells (& Print as desired).

Link Cell To a Sheet in this Workbook:

1. Right Click Image in cell, Select Link, Dialogue opens.
2. In the "Link to:" section, Select "Place in This Document".
3. Modify the cell reference as desired.
4. Select "ScreenTip..." and enter the mouse over text if desired. Click OK
5. Click OK.

Alternate: Entire cell as clickable link (not just image).

1. Follow steps for placing an image in a spreadsheet cell (someplace out of the way).
2. Copy this cell (not the image). Select the cell with the arrow keys instead of the mouse may be easier, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to copy.
3. Right click the cell for the link, Paste Special..., Other Paste Options section (at bottom), clipboard on right with links (there are two like this), Select the one with screentip or label "Linked Picture" (not "Paste Link").
4. Complete Step 3 of "Insert Picture Into Cell - Lock the image into the cell"
5. Complete all steps of "Link Cell To a Sheet in this Workbook". Note for step 1: Right Click the Cell (since the entire cell is one with the image - *source: Yoda*).

Comment: Yes sir, thanks a lot. i have done it. complete all the steps but there is a problem. names C1.jpg is the picture name and when completing all these steps when click on the image C.jpg excel sheet dont opens ????? –

Comment: This solution does not use any picture names. You have posted the same comment to two different solutions. To which solution does your comment apply?

Comment: i just want open the specific cell of the excel sheet when i click on the picture. do you know how do that?

Comment: @AdnanKhan In this answer under the section: **Link Cell To a Sheet in this Workbook:** - **Step 3. Modify the cell reference as desired.** The answer provides this exact instruction on linking to a specific cell. Also of note, since you seem to be struggling with the macro issues, this answer does not use macros. The result can be achieved using the built in Excel formula or by using the Ribbon Link button or by right clicking...

Comment: ok thanks.  working on it and if solved will let you know

Comment: after completing step 3 successfully cannot open the cell when click on thepicture. forexample in the cell "placed p5.png when i click on it the P5.png opens the picture but want to do the other way around. want to open the excel sheet when i click on P5.png. the P5.png is on desktop

Comment: Do not combine the steps to **Insert Picture Into Cell** and the steps to **Link Cell To a Sheet in this Workbook**. They are two distinct processes. The first process places an image in the cell. The second process creates a link with an object already in the workbook to a chosen place.

Comment: Do not place the picture name "placed p5.png" in the cell. Use the instructions to **Insert Picture Into Cell**. If the file is on the desktop, then clicking on it will have no effect on Excel unless it is a shortcut in some manner of speaking to Excel. Only the clicks inside the Excel app can be seen by Excel.

Answer (score 1):

## User Scenario: Clicking Windows Desktop Pic to Open Excel

Specifically, an Excel Workbook's Worksheet and Cell associated with the product in the icon image.
Assumes the user will be clicking an icon of a product image, either on the desktop or in some other folder. 
*Previous answers assumed the images were in the cells of a worksheet inside an Excel workbook.*

In order to implement this solution, first create Icon Images for each product. There are tutorials and websites which do these conversions. Some products can place multiple icons into a single file. Once the product images are converted to an icon file or files, proceed.

### Here is the solution:

```
With createobject("Excel.Application")
    .Goto .Workbooks.Open(WScript.Arguments.Named.Item("book")). _
        Worksheets(WScript.Arguments.Named.Item("sheet")). _
        Range(WScript.Arguments.Named.Item("range"))
    .visible = True
End With
```

- Save the code to a file named **ExcelShortcuts.vbs** and be sure the file has the ".vbs" extension.
- Create a shortcut to this file. (quick tip, drag the file icon and hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> before and while releasing the left mouse button.)
- Rename the shortcut *Product_1_Name*, whatever that may be (no filename extension needed).
- Right click the *Product_1_Name* file shortcut icon and select `Properties`.
- In the *Properties* dialogue, select the `Shortcut` tab and make these two changes:

  1. In the `Target` text box, at the end after `...\ExcelShortcuts.vbs` (and after any closing quote):

     - Add a space and `/book:"C:\Users\name\Desktop\ProductWorkbook.xlsx" /sheet:Sheet1 /range:A1`
     - `/book:FilePath\FileName` Replace the file path and name as appropriate for the product
     - `/sheet:Sheet1` Change `Sheet1` to the sheet name for the product. If the *Sheet Name* has spaces, use quotes starting right after the `:`. `/sheet:"Quote Special Chars ! too"`
     - `/range:A1` Change the `A1` to the cell address to focus on.
  2. Click `Change Icon...`

     - Navigate to the folder (`Browse`) with the product icon pictures and select the image for this product.
     - Click `OK`
- Click `OK`

Now there is a shortcut with the product image on it. The shortcut is to the special VBSCript which will open Excel. The script will use the arguments supplied to the shortcut to know which Workbook to open and which Worksheet to turn to and which cell to focus on.

Make more shortcuts to the **ExcelShortcuts.vbs** script. Rename each one to a product name. Modify the shortcuts Target (add /book: /sheet: /range:) and change the icon image to one which represents the product.

Edit - Fixed VBS file extension.

Comment: excellent i think this is gone a work

Comment: there is an another small task which is much more simpler than the previous one so if do that then have to the one which use excel. Task: Create a catalog of the products so that when click on the picture of the product price  appears.? Do know how to do that?

Comment: Are you saying the catalog is an excel workbook?

Comment: forget about excel. The main task is: when the person click on the photo of the product, pop up price or appear price wheather its in  a catalog form or whatever is it. do u know how to do it?

Comment: @AdnanKhan, I cannot *forget about excel*, you tagged your question as Microsoft-Excel. I have tried to glean what it is you want and cannot understand what it is you are trying to accomplish. It seems there is a picture **somewhere** and when it is clicked on **something** will show the price. You must define where the picture lives. And where the price lives. If the picture is a thumbnail of an image on the desktop (or some other folder), then this is the wrong venue for your question. If Excel is not part of the solution, then this is the wrong venue for your question.

Comment: The pictures are in a folder. the prices are excel sheet. the prices can write manually with each picture. the main thing is to put all the pictures toagther or make a catalog so that when click on each picture shows its price.(i can insert the prices manually which are saved in excel).

Comment: Since the picture is a thumbnail of an image on the desktop (or some other folder), this is the wrong venue for your question. If you make a sheet of pictures in the Excel workbook, then use my first answer. If you want to make icons for the pictures, then use this answer.